# when using .configure and make command when building c++ with .configure script project in emscripten it fails

Tags: linux, executable, webassembly, configure, emconfigure

I am failing when trying to build `php.wasm` (`php-cli.wasm`). What am I doing wrong? It is asking me to give flags for `libxml` which is not there in `./configure` command only but there with `docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src -u $(id -u):$(id -g) emscripten/emsdk emconfigure ./configure`

https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk/issues/1253

```
sudo docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src -u $(id -u):$(id -g) emscripten/emsdk emconfigure ./configure
configure: ./configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
shtool:echo:Warning: unable to determine terminal sequence for bold mode
shtool:echo:Warning: unable to determine terminal sequence for bold mode
checking for pkg-config... no
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc -E
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether _XOPEN_SOURCE should be defined... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking whether to enable runpaths... yes
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for bison... no
checking for re2c... no
checking for php... no
checking whether to enable computed goto gcc extension with re2c... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -fvisibility=hidden... yes
checking whether to force non-PIC code in shared modules... no
checking whether we are using musl libc... no
checking whether to use -D_GNU_SOURCE cflag... yes
checking whether /dev/urandom exists... yes
checking for global register variables support... no
checking whether __cpuid_count is available... no
checking for pthreads_cflags... -pthread
checking for pthreads_lib... pthread

Configuring SAPI modules
checking for Apache 2 handler module support via DSO through APXS... no
checking for setproctitle... no
checking for sys/pstat.h... no
checking for PS_STRINGS... no
checking for CLI build... yes
checking for embedded SAPI library support... no
checking for FPM build... no
checking for clang fuzzer SAPI... no
checking for LiteSpeed support... no
checking for phpdbg support... yes
checking for phpdbg debug build... no
checking for phpdbg readline support... no
checking whether termios.h defines TIOCGWINSZ... no
checking whether sys/ioctl.h defines TIOCGWINSZ... yes
checking for phpdbg and readline integration... disabled
checking for userfaultfd faulting on write-protected memory support... no
checking for CGI build... yes
checking for sun_len in sys/un.h... no
checking whether cross-process locking is required by accept()... no
checking for chosen SAPI module... none
checking for executable SAPI binaries...  cli phpdbg cgi

Running system checks
checking for sendmail... /usr/sbin/sendmail
checking whether system uses EBCDIC... no
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether writing to stdout works... This is the test message -- 
yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for socketpair... yes
checking for htonl... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for gethostbyaddr... yes
checking for dlopen... yes
checking for dlsym... yes
checking for sin in -lm... yes
checking for inet_aton... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking for arpa/nameser.h... yes
checking for crypt.h... yes
checking for dns.h... no
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for grp.h... yes
checking for ieeefp.h... no
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking for linux/filter.h... no
checking for linux/sock_diag.h... no
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for os/signpost.h... no
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for pty.h... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking for resolv.h... yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking for sysexits.h... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/statfs.h... yes
checking for sys/statvfs.h... yes
checking for sys/vfs.h... yes
checking for sys/sysexits.h... no
checking for sys/uio.h... yes
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking for sys/loadavg.h... no
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for unix.h... no
checking for utime.h... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking for sys/ipc.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for tmmintrin.h... no
checking for nmmintrin.h... no
checking for wmmintrin.h... no
checking for immintrin.h... yes
checking for fopencookie... yes
checking for broken getcwd... no
checking for broken gcc optimize-strlen... no
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc options needed to detect all undeclared functions... none needed
checking for struct tm.tm_zone... yes
checking for missing declarations of reentrant functions... done
checking for fclose declaration... ok
checking for struct flock... yes
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking size of intmax_t... 8
checking size of ssize_t... 4
checking size of ptrdiff_t... 4
checking size of short... 2
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 4
checking size of long long... 8
checking size of size_t... 4
checking size of off_t... 8
checking for int8_t... yes
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for __builtin_expect... yes
checking for __builtin_clz... yes
checking for __builtin_clzl... yes
checking for __builtin_clzll... yes
checking for __builtin_ctzl... yes
checking for __builtin_ctzll... yes
checking for __builtin_smull_overflow... yes
checking for __builtin_smulll_overflow... yes
checking for __builtin_saddl_overflow... yes
checking for __builtin_saddll_overflow... yes
checking for __builtin_ssubl_overflow... yes
checking for __builtin_ssubll_overflow... yes
checking for __builtin_cpu_init... no
checking for __builtin_cpu_supports... no
checking whether the compiler supports __alignof__... yes
checking for struct tm.tm_gmtoff... yes
checking for struct stat.st_blksize... yes
checking for struct stat.st_rdev... yes
checking for struct stat.st_blocks... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_storage... yes
checking for field sa_len in struct sockaddr... no
checking for __attribute__((ifunc))... no
checking for __attribute__((target))... no
checking for IPv6 support... yes
checking for alphasort... yes
checking for asctime_r... yes
checking for chroot... yes
checking for ctime_r... yes
checking for explicit_memset... no
checking for fdatasync... yes
checking for flock... yes
checking for ftok... no
checking for funopen... no
checking for gai_strerror... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for getloadavg... yes
checking for getlogin... yes
checking for getprotobyname... yes
checking for getprotobynumber... yes
checking for getservbyname... yes
checking for getservbyport... yes
checking for getrusage... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for gmtime_r... yes
checking for getpwnam_r... yes
checking for getgrnam_r... yes
checking for getpwuid_r... yes
checking for getwd... no
checking for glob... yes
checking for inet_ntoa... yes
checking for inet_ntop... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for lchown... yes
checking for memcntl... no
checking for memmove... yes
checking for mkstemp... yes
checking for mmap... yes
checking for nice... yes
checking for nl_langinfo... yes
checking for poll... yes
checking for pthread_jit_write_protect_np... no
checking for putenv... yes
checking for scandir... yes
checking for setitimer... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for shutdown... yes
checking for sigprocmask... yes
checking for statfs... yes
checking for statvfs... yes
checking for std_syslog... no
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strnlen... yes
checking for strptime... yes
checking for strtok_r... yes
checking for symlink... yes
checking for tzset... yes
checking for unsetenv... yes
checking for usleep... yes
checking for utime... yes
checking for vasprintf... yes
checking for asprintf... yes
checking for nanosleep... yes
checking for memmem... yes
checking for memrchr... yes
checking for strerror_r... yes
checking how many arguments gethostbyname_r() takes... six
checking for nanosleep in -lrt... yes
checking for setsockopt in -lnetwork... no
checking for __setsockopt in -lnetwork... no
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking for copy_file_range... no
checking for strlcat... yes
checking for strlcpy... yes
checking for explicit_bzero... yes
checking for getopt... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for type of reentrant time-related functions... POSIX
checking for in_addr_t... yes
checking for aarch64 CRC32 API... no
checking for asm goto... yes
checking whether to enable valgrind support... yes
checking for valgrind... no
checking for openpty... yes

General settings
checking whether to include gcov symbols... no
checking whether to include debugging symbols... no
checking whether to enable debug assertions in release mode... no
checking whether to dlopen extensions with RTLD_NOW instead of RTLD_LAZY... no
checking layout of installed files... PHP
checking path to configuration file... DEFAULT
checking where to scan for configuration files... 
checking whether to enable PHP's own SIGCHLD handler... no
checking whether to explicitly link against libgcc... no
checking whether to enable short tags by default... yes
checking whether to enable dmalloc... no
checking whether to enable IPv6 support... yes
checking whether to enable DTrace support... no
checking how big to make fd sets... using system default

Configuring extensions
checking for io.h... no
checking for strtoll... yes
checking for atoll... yes
checking whether to build with LIBXML support... yes
checking for libxml-2.0 >= 2.9.0... no
configure: error: in `/src':
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBXML_CFLAGS
and LIBXML_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

To get pkg-config, see <http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/>.
See `config.log' for more details
emconfigure: error: './configure' failed (returned 1)
```

[config.log](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk/files/11982166/config.log)

This is what happens when you run just the `./configure` command.

the `docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src -u $(id -u):$(id -g) emscripten/emsdk emconfigure ./configure  --disable-libxml` failed even with the disable tag. i also tried with giving the flag paths for libxml needed flags and it failed. probably it did not take the flag at all. i installed with apt-get install   `libxml2` but did not try with `libxml2-dev`

I am trying to build the r-lang project using the command `/workspaces/codespaces-blank/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emconfigure ./configure` and the `/workspaces/codespaces-blank/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcmake make` and get simlar error for ./configure where is not able to find the installed `gofortran` (both gfortran and gfortran-9-dev are installed) - `/workspaces/codespaces-blank/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emconfigure ./configure MAKE=gmake`

Comment: How about installing libxml2-dev before compiling PHP?

Comment: It was installed. I have both libxml2 and libxml2-dev installed. it somehow failed tracing the paths or asking for the env variable declarations. a env variable declaration did not help.